# auth0-js: UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found, though logged in

Tags: express, vue.js, authorization, jwt, auth0

I created an app with Vue (including Vue-Router), Node and Express.
I'm trying to secure my App with SSO, using auth0-js.
I created an Auth0-Account and followed [this](https://auth0.com/blog/vuejs2-authentication-tutorial/) tutorial.
My Login function looks as follows:

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js'
var auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
  clientID: <my-client-id>,
  domain: '<my-auth0-domain>/'
})

export function ssoLogin () {
  auth.authorize({
    responseType: 'token id_token'
    redirectUri: http://localhost:8000/callback,
    audience: 'https://<my-auth0-domain>/userinfo',
    scope: 'full_access'
  })
}
```

While the login itself works fine, I can't seem to find out how to secure the secret routes of my app.

Following the above mentioned tutorial, I used express-jwt and jwks-rsa, like this:

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt')
var jwks = require('jwks-rsa')
var authCheck = jwt({
  secret: jwks.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: "https://<my-auth0-domain>/.well-known/jwks.json"
  }),
  audience: <my-client-id>,
  issuer: "https://<my-auth0-domain>/",
  algorithms: ['RS256']
})

app.post('/send-sensitive-data', authCheck, function (req, res) {
  // this post requests sends some data, and should only do so, if a user is logged in
})
```

However, even if I'm logged in via SSO, when I try to access the sensitive data, I obtain

```
UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
```

I have no idea where I went wrong. This seems like a very stupid question, but: Can somebody tell me, where the authorization token must be, so it will be found?

I would really appreciate if someone helped me by this or gave me a hint.
Please feel free to ask for more code snippets, if that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer on my own ... but in case anyone is making the same mistake as I'm doing: I forgot to set the header in the axios.post request, like that:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/send-sensitive-data',
  data: somedata,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken()
  }
})
.then(response => {
  // do something with the response
})
```